# Use PHP templates as blocks

Tags: templates, block-editor

I need many "Reusable Blocks", but creating and maintaining them takes too long.

I'd like to do this:

- create a PHP-based "template" file, e.g. `wp-content/foo/bar.php`
- create a page in the block editor, and insert/include that "template"

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

[Block Patterns](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-patterns/) probably will suit your needs. They're written in PHP, designed so you can create layouts (like a heading, gallery, and button together) but the content (e.g. what the text of the heading is, etc) is unique each time that you use them.

[A good overview and roundup of how they're being used](https://gutenbergtimes.com/the-wordpress-block-patterns-resource-list/) is at the Gutenberg Times.